# Friedman test and post-hoc test for Python

Tags: python, nonparametric, post-hoc, generalized-estimating-equations, friedman-test

In my dataset, I have five (ordinal) groups with an x-amount of measurement. Because homoscedasticity is violated, I performed the Friedman chi-square test to see if there are any statistical differences between the groups:

```
fried = stats.friedmanchisquare(*[grp for idx, grp in df.iteritems()]))
```

This returned a statistical difference, but now I would like to find out between which groups the differences exist. In `R` there is a nice solution for this ([Friedman's test and post-hoc analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10309/friedmans-test-and-post-hoc-analysis), https://www.r-statistics.com/2010/02/post-hoc-analysis-for-friedmans-test-r-code/), where they use the Wilcoxon-Nemenyi-McDonald-Thompson test, but I am unable to find one for Python.

**Is there a possibility to do post-hoc analyses for the Friedman test?** Alternatively, what would we be a good alternative for the Friedman test that does allow me to compare between groups, e.g. a generalized estimating equation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am currently looking into this issue myself; according to this [paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/v7/demsar06a) there are a number of possibilities to perform posthoc-tests (**Update**: an extension regarding the use of non-parametric tests can be found [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020025509005404)):

- Perform the [Nemenyi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemenyi_test)-test for all pairwise combinations; this is similar to the [Tukey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey's_range_test)-test for ANOVA.
- Perform the [Bonferroni-Dunn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction)-test; in this setting one compares all values to a list of control values.
- Alternatively, one can perform step-up and step-down procedures sequentially testing hypotheses ordered by their significance. One can use [Holm's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holm%E2%80%93Bonferroni_method) step-down procedure, [Hochberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate#Hochberg.27s_step-up_procedure_.281988.29)'s step-up procedure or [Hommel](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Courses/956/ResourceDetails/MultipleComparision/Hommel88.pdf)'s procedure.

The [STAC Python library](http://tec.citius.usc.es/stac/doc/) seems to include all these tests, except for Hommel's procedure.

Answer (score 4):

Complementing the other answer, since you asked about implementation of the post-hoc tests in Python: the Orange library implements the post-hoc tests (Nemenyi and Bonferroni-Dunn), including a function to draw a Critical Difference diagram [1]

http://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/data-mining-library/reference/evaluation.cd.html (see the section "CD diagram")

[1] Janez Demsar, Statistical Comparisons of Classifiers over Multiple Data Sets, 7(Jan):1–30, 2006.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform any of the following tests with [scikit-posthocs](https://github.com/maximtrp/scikit-posthocs/) package: Conover, Nemenyi, Siegel, and Miller post-hoc tests.